# multiple execution when using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

```
my code:
    s<-function(v,k){
      ifelse(k>length(v),print("error,k>length(v)"),return(v-k))
    }
    v=1:5
    k=6
    s(v,k)
```

output:

```
> s(v,k)
[1] "error,k>length(v)"
[1] "error,k>length(v)"
```

1. Why is this printing twice? thanks
2. Is there some kind of error handler I could use here?

Comment: don't use `ifelse` if you are comparing the single quantity. `s<-function(v,k){
        if(k>length(v)){print("error,k>length(v)")
        }else {
            return((v-k))
        }
}
v=1:5
k=6
s(v,k)`

Comment: ok it just looks neater. It's still baffling why it's printing twice. if the statement is false it only executes once.

Comment: Don't use `return` in `ifelse`. Furthermore `print` has both a side-effect and a value.

Comment: Why not use return? actually I just changed the print to return and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `print` explicitly in the function and returning the value. If you assign the result of the function to a variable, the second "print" is suppressed.

```
> x <- s(v, k)
[1] "error,k>length(v)"
```

This is also achievable using `invisible`.

```
> invisible(s(v, k))
[1] "error,k>length(v)"
```